# ExecutorService-like class where user controls when Callables are called

Tags: java, android, executorservice, callable

I was using an ExecutorService to schedule tasks to be executed in future. After seeing some "odd" behavior where my Callable was getting executed before I called get() on the Future object returned by submitting my Callable to the ExecutorService pool, I read some documentation and found that the submitted task will get executed between the time it gets submitted or at the latest when get() is called on the Future object.

My question - is there any class that would allow Callables to be submitted to it and ONLY executed when get() is called on it? At this point, it seems like just managing the Callables myself and calling call() on them myself when I am ready for them to be executed seems like it'd accomplish what I want, but I wanted to make sure there was no service already implemented that accomplished this.

In short, is there any alternative to ExecutorService that lets me control when Callables submitted to it are called? Note - the time in the future that I want them called is variable and not determined as I may decide not to call them so a ScheduledExecutorService pool won't work here.

Thanks much!

Comment: How is that different from calling `call()` synchronously? What good would the threads do?

Comment: It's not necessarily. I was just asking to make sure there was no service that already handles this. Given the answer below, my suspicions that I should just manually do this (as you also suggest) is the way to go!

Comment: Note that Future.get() is a synchronous call, it blocks the calling thread execution and make it wait for the callable to finish, hence sacrifice the benefit of callable (which should be running asynchronously), Unless you have a very special requirements, do not use and rely on it in your code. Auto-managed task execution is a feature of ExecutorService, if this doesn't fit your demand, simply don't use it and use callable.call()/runnable.run() directly in you code whenever you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you really want to use a `Queue<Callable>` instead and just poll the queue for tasks.

That way you can submit as many tasks as you like and execute them at your will - one by one.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the confirmation and quick response! :)